# How to get out of this cycle?

Tags: c#, cycle

All kind time of day! The question is the cycle: write code with the last 2 lines are defined as unreachable code, because when you press any key of the case starts an infinite loop. Experience in programming is little and does not understand. How to get out of this cycle? Here's the code of the program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
namespace ConsoleApplication3
    {
    class Hero
    {
        public int x = 0;
        public int y = 0;
        public int hp = 3;
        public double power = 3;
        public void printHero()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" x={0},y={1},hp={2},power={3}", x, y, hp, power);
        }
        public void hitHero()
        {
            hp = hp - 1;
        }
        public void attackHero()
        {
            power = power - 0.5;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hero hero;
            hero = new Hero();
            ConsoleKeyInfo keypress;
            keypress = Console.ReadKey();
            while (true)
            {
                switch (keypress.KeyChar)
                {
                    case 'A':
                        hero.x = hero.x - 1;
                        hero.printHero();
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        hero.x = hero.x +1;
                        hero.printHero();
                        break;
                    case 'W':
                        hero.y = hero.y + 1;
                        hero.printHero();
                        break;
                    case 'S':
                        hero.y = hero.y - 1;
                        hero.printHero();
                        break;
                    case 'E':
                        hero.attackHero();
                        hero.printHero();
                        break;
                    case 'X':
                        hero.hitHero();
                        hero.printHero();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            } 
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` is an infinite loop.  Because `true` will never *not* be `true`.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: *"How to get out of this cycle"* well, how do you *want* to get out of the cycle? Is it when any of the listed actions where executed, is it when no action is selected or is it on some specific key pressed or does it depend on the sun outside your window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's always the `break` command. You can flag that after a key has been pushed, you want to break. And then outside the `switch`, you `break`. However, why do you need to have a `while(true)` loop anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You have to query for key *inside* the loop:

```
while (true)
{
    keypress = Console.ReadKey(); // continuously check for key presses
    switch (keypress.KeyChar) // process new keypresses
    {
        case 'A':
...
```

and don't forget to break the loop at some point (e.g. when some condition is met or certain key is pressed):

```
...

    if(endCondition)
        break; // will exit while(true)
}
```